# Words with accents show with symbols when read from the database

Tags: java, oracle, encoding, utf-8, wicket

I have an app that sends an email to the user when he doesn´t login for X months.

An example of a message is as follows:

```
"Informa-se que este utilizador não efetua Login no SGES há mais de três meses. Caso o utilizador já não se encontre ativo, por favor, contacte o administrador do SGES da sua entidade, para que o perfil do utilizador seja removido do sistema."
```

But in the email received with that message, it shows like this:

```
“Informa-se que este utilizador n�o efetua Login no SGES h� mais de tr�s meses. Caso o utilizador j� n�o se encontre ativo, por favor, contacte o administrador do SGES da sua entidade, para que o perfil do utilizador seja removido do sistema.”
```

I'm not showing any code because I'm not sure what to show in this particular case.
When I'm retrieving the message, I'm only doing a getMessage from the column from the database.

Any way to fix?

Comment: This usually indicates an encoding issue. You're storing the message with a certain encoding (for example UTF-8) but then you're reading the message using another encoding (for example UTF-16) so this is causing all the characters that have different bytes in the reading encoding to be shown as unknown symbols.

Comment: Let's eliminate your user's viewer as being a defective piece of software. This leads me to ask - did you set headers indicating char encoding correctly so his viewer can use the correct encoding? Or, is there some way your encoding is wrong *before* you create the mail?